# Loop through DataTable and select only certain values in column

Tags: c#, dictionary, datatable

I have a DataTable from which I would like to loop through each row and column and then select a value from a specific column depending on the other values in the columns/each row.

My code currently looks like this:

```
 foreach (DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
 {
     foreach (DataColumn dcol in dt.Columns)
     {
         foreach (var Item in ImportData)
         {
             if (Item.Value.Equals(true))
             {
                 if (Item.Key.Equals("" + dcol))
                 {
                     string value = drow[dcol].ToString();
                     if (value.Equals("X"))
                     {
                         outDraws += drow["Drawing"].ToString();
                         outDraws += "\n";
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

ImportData is a `Dictionary<string, bool>`, which holds the data that I want to compare with my DataTable.

`string outDraws` is just a string which should hold the content of the drawings I want to print out.

My problem now is that I only want to print out the content in the column 'Drawing' of the row where all columns with the same name as the Keys in ImportData have 'X' as value. At the moment I'm getting all the rows where any of the columns have 'X' as value and has the same name as any Key in ImportData.

I understand that it will be quite hard for you to get what I want to do but please ask if you need any more information and I will try to provide.

Many thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

ImportData contains the name of different products as keys. These products have either been selected or not by the customer through another program, if they have been selected they have the value true and if not selected they have the value false.

With the method presented above I would like to compare ALL the keys that have the value true with the column names in the DataTable. If the column name corresponds to the key in ImportData (which is the name of a product) then I want to check if that column in a specific row has 'X' as value.

This goes on for ALL the keys in ImportData and in the end I should know which row in the DataTable that has an 'X' in all the columns with the same name as the keys in ImportData. For this row I would like to get the content of the column called 'Drawing'. 
So for an example say that ImportData contains:

[Motor, true][Product6, true][Product7, true]

Then I would like to print out the column Drawing at row 6.

Unfortunately I can't post pictures..

Comment: Then only check the drawing column, not all columns?

Comment: I would like to check all columns, and only where there is an 'X' for all the columns with the same name as ALL the keys in ImportData I would like to print out the drawing column

Comment: Please explain more thorougly what ImportData contains, what's in the data table and what you want to achieve. Maybe add a simple but complete sample that compiles as a console application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with any problem: divide and conquer. Break down your problem in smaller pieces and go from there.

From what I understand, you want to do something with certain rows from the datatable. Something like:

```
 foreach (var drow in dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>())
 {
     if (SomeConditionIsMet(dt, drow, ImportData))
     {
         outDraws += drow["Drawing"].ToString();
         outDraws += "\n";
     }
 }
```

The function SomeConditionIsMetcould looks like this:

```
private static bool SomeConditionIsMet(
                         DataTable dt, DataRow drow, 
                         IDictionary<string, bool> importData)
{
   // TODO if the condition is met, return true
   // otherwise, return false
}
```

Now your problem is simplified to thinking about what it means that 'Some condition is met'. Once you can clearly express that in words, rename the function to reflect that (e.g. to 'AllColumnsAreChecked')

Here's a sample with solution as I understand it:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var importData = new Dictionary<string, bool>()
        {
            {"Product1", true},
            {"Product2", false},
            {"Product3", true},
        };

        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Product1");
        dt.Columns.Add("Product2");
        dt.Columns.Add("Product3");
        dt.Columns.Add("Product4");
        dt.Columns.Add("Drawing");

        // row1 should be added
        var row1 = dt.NewRow();
        row1["Product1"] = "X";
        row1["Product3"] = "X";
        row1["Drawing"] = "Drawing1";
        dt.Rows.Add(row1);

        // row2 should not be added
        var row2 = dt.NewRow();
        row2["Product1"] = "X";
        row2["Drawing"] = "Drawing2";
        dt.Rows.Add(row2);

        string outDraws = string.Empty;

        foreach (DataRow drow in dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>())
        {
            if (AllColumnsAreChecked(drow, importData))
            {
                outDraws += drow["Drawing"].ToString();
                outDraws += "\n";
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(outDraws);
    }

    private static bool AllColumnsAreChecked(DataRow drow, Dictionary<string, bool> importData)
    {
        foreach (var key in importData.Keys)
        {
            if (!importData[key])
                continue;
            var value = drow[key] as string;
            if (value != "X")
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Bonus: here's a LINQ based implementation of the check:

```
    private static bool AllColumnsAreChecked(DataRow drow, Dictionary<string, bool> importData)
    {
        return importData.Keys
            .Where(k => importData.ContainsKey(k) && importData[k]) // the field must be enabled in importData
            .All(k => (drow[k] as string) == "X"); // the corresponding value in the row must be 'X'
     }
```

Comment: Yes maybe that's a good idea, I'll try that. As mentioned above I understood when I posted it that it would be hard for me to describe exactly what I want to do. Hopefully I can come up with a solution.

Comment: First think about the *problem*, then about the solution. If you can clearly describe the problem, the solution will present itself naturally.

Comment: "My problem now is that I only want to print out the content in the column 'Drawing' of the row where all columns with the same name as the Keys in ImportData have 'X' as value". That's my problem..

Comment: I mean, I get the content Drawings exactly as I want to but now I get all the drawings where ANY of the column names appear in ImportData and I would only like the drawing where ALL of the column names appear in ImportData.

Comment: Many thanks! You really did understand me haha. Really, thank you for your answer that was exactly what I wanted to do.

Comment: You're welcome. Next time, create a full sample yourself. Makes it easier for everyone to understand/answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
{
    object cellData = row["colName"];
}
```